# Get the folder with "greatest index"

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, directory

I have a project on .net code on which I am working with files.

I have a lot of folders and the naming convention is like this :

```
pdf(1)
pdf(2)
pdf(3)
pdf(4)
pdf(5)
```

What I have to do is when I insert a new folder, it's new name should be `(# of folders that exist+ 1)`
And this code does that very well:

```
 string FileDirectory = "C\\test\\myfiles\\";
 string FileName = "pdf";
 DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(FileDirectory);

            FileSystemInfo[] filesAndDirs = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFileSystemInfos("*" + FileName + "*");
            int i = filesAndDirs.Length;
            
            if (i>0)
            {
                    i++;
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(FileDirectory + '\\' + FileName+ "(" + i + ")");
            }
```

Now, although this code works alright, there is this scenario when it doesn't.
E.g, existing files are:

```
pdf(1)
pdf(2)
pdf(5)
pdf(6),
```

it will try to create a new folder,(# of folders + i) and that would be "pdf(5)" but "pdf(5)"  already exists!

Now my question is: how can I get the highest "index" of the existing folders (6) on this example, and create a new folder pdf(6)+1 ?

Comment: Loop through, split out the number part. Alternatively [use regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester) such as `^.*?\((\d+)\)$` to capture the number.

Comment: Do you want heights index from that folder names?

Comment: @ZoyebShaikh, if possible, then yes. And then I will compare it and take the maximum of it, then just "maximumim + 1".

Comment: @Llama, can you please give me a pseudo-code at least ?

Comment: Loop through the directories. If the directory contains `(` and ends with `)`, then take the directory name that comes before the `(` as the "root". Use `Substring`, `IndexOf`, `LastIndexOf`, etc. to cut out the number portion. If that number is higher than the last recorded one for that directory, then save it. If no `(` then assume 1 and and store it. Once you have looped through all of the directories, you should have the "root" and the highest number for each directory. If still confused, try working out how you would do it on paper.

Comment: sure I can do it for you @questioner9928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
 

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            List<string> files = new List<string>{"pdf(1)","pdf(2)","pdf(3)"};
            List<string> nums = new List<string>();


            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var str = file.Substring(file.IndexOf("(")).Replace(")","").Replace("(","");
                nums.Add(str);
            }


            var fileNums =  nums.ConvertAll(x=>x);
            var lastfileNo = fileNums.OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault();

        }

    }

}
```

there might be another way around also

first loop through files and store it to list of string
then convert all into an int, if you wish not to convert then it's fine
then order by descending and find the first one

Comment: Makes sense, but my filenames are not always "pdf(1),pdf(2),pdf(3)". How to make it dynamically, e.g: `List<string> files = new List<string>{FileName"}; `? I mean, store all the founded folders in a list, not statically put their names in a List.

Comment: you must use the System.IO namespace and classes to get all files Name, do you want me to provide those codes also?

Comment: your question was "how can I get the highest "index" of the existing folders (6) " so this is how you can get the highest index, wasn't it?

Comment: Well yes, it is actually a very good idea on how  to achieve that and it works perfectly. Now I just need one more loop to store all my founded folders in the List. I'll try to solve this.

Comment: ZoeybShaikh do you have any ide why [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) loop is not working? It returns an empty array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240329/discussion-between-zoyeb-shaikh-and-questioner9928).